# Некорректно отображается рамка вокруг div

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Необходимо блок поместить в рамку. Но при border: solid 1px grey; отображается только верхняя часть рамки(не хватает нижней рамки, правой и левой). Что необходимо сделать?

```css
.zagolovok{ 
 border: solid 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="post container">
<article>
  <div class="zagolovok">
    <a href="#"><h1 class="head_book">Hello</h1></a>
  </div>
  <img src="eb9f35bcbd6bd32d0782365ea2722014.jpg" class="img_book">
</article>
<footer>
</div>
```

Comment: я выполняю Ваш код, и у меня вся рамка видна

Comment: Рамка работает нормально